# how to make dynamic data objects in ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

https://jsfiddle.net/c7n34e3x/1/ out of `data` / `data1` / `data2` only `data` works but it is not dynamic

this works

```
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://domain/api/v2/playlists/",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\"playlist_content\" :{\"content_id\" : \"ef0a30ef-3198-4ce6-8927-e390257776ed\"}}"
  }
```

but i need the data to be dynamic like below.. see `content_id`

```
  var content_id = $(this).val();
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://domain/api/v2/playlists/",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\"playlist_content\" :{\"content_id\" : \""+content_id+"\"}}"
  }
```

but this is not working. what can i do to dynamically create the data setting? This may read better with syntax highlighting.

`"data": {"playlist_content" : {"content_id" : content_id}}` this also does not work

here is a fiddle with a temporary token https://jsfiddle.net/c7n34e3x/

Comment: It is due to `$(this).val()`, it must be returning something wrong, you are appending `content_id` correctly into the `settings.data` field

Comment: even if i change `var content_id = $(this).val()` to `var content_id = 123456` it does not work

Comment: Show the error then, on my console it works.

Comment: *"it does not work"* is not a proper technical problem statement. What part doesn't work? What does your error handling indicate? If response is sent back, what does it tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried like this?

```
var content_id = $(this).val();
var data = JSON.stringify({"playlist_content" : {"content_id" : content_id}});
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://domain/api/v2/playlists/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": data
}
```

Ok as per JSFiddle demo updated code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/c7n34e3x/3/). It works everytime with proper credentials.

Comment: that object isn't json and needs to be stringified

Comment: if i do it right. i get a success response... if i do it wrong then i get mixed domain errors

Comment: `stringify` leads to this error `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: i will make a jsfiddle...  dont leave yet :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c7n34e3x/  ok `var data` works but when i try to make it dynamic like `var data1`... it does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141688/discussion-between-omar-and-mahesh-singh-chouhan).